# What is another verb to use in this sentence "I stop at this step and unable to continue"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

I have been using "get stuck" in a sentence like "I get stuck at this step and can't move on" . But by googling I don't see it is used as much. Is there a more common way to say this?

Comment: What kind of step is it, and why do you stop at it? Note that *get stuck* and *stop* don't necessarily mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that saying “can’t move on” would be unnecessary in most cases, as steps are usually sequential.

I also feel it’s slightly more idiomatic to substitute “on” for “at”.

So I’d say simply:

> I get stuck on this step.

Also, to be clear, saying “I get stuck” implies you are saying that you frequently get stuck at the same point in a process. If you are describing the point you’re at after getting stuck, you’d say:

> I **got** stuck on this step.